# Mocking methods using Mockito in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mockito

Using mockito in python for a scenario like this:

```
import os
import unittest
from mockito import when, verify

def interesting_function():
    os.system('mkdir some_dir')
    another_function()

def another_function():
    print('Done')
```

Something like this works:

```
class InterestingFunctionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_interesting_function(self):
         when(os).system('mkdir some_dir').thenReturn(0)
         interesting_function()
         verify(os).system('mkdir some_dir')
```

But how can I mock `another_function` ? Is this even possible? Can I mock methods which exist outside of classes? Something like this for example does not work:

```
class InterestingFunctionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_interesting_function(self):
         when(file_name).another_function().thenReturn()
         interesting_function()
         verify(file_name).another_function()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [when2 with function](https://mockito-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the-functions.html#mockito.when2). There is no `verify2` working similarily with functions though.

```py
class InterestingFunctionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_interesting_function(self):
         with when2(another_function, ANY).thenReturn():
             interesting_function()
             # verify() ??
```

**Update:**

Functions are also objects in Python, so what you can do is:

```py
class InterestingFunctionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_interesting_function(self):
         when(another_function).__call__().thenReturn()
         interesting_function()
         verify(another_function).__call__()
```