# Python mockito: mock a single function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito

I need to mock a single function (not a class member and not a part of an imported module) in mockito. I read that mockito mocks are callable so I can use `__call__()` function but unfortunately it does not work for me. There is an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427945/mocking-methods-using-mockito-in-python) about it asked 3 years ago and I suppose that maybe something has changes since that time (so please do not resolve this question as a duplicate of that old thread).

Here is the example code (taken from that old thread):

```
import os
import unittest
from mockito import when, verify

def interesting_function():
    os.system('mkdir some_dir')
    another_function()

def another_function():
    print('Done')

class InterestingFunctionTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_interesting_function(self):
         when(another_function).__call__().thenReturn()
         interesting_function()
         verify(another_function).__call__()
```

It was supposed to work I'm getting the following error:

```
mockito.verification.VerificationError:
Wanted but not invoked:

    __call__()

Instead got:

    Nothing
```

How can I mock and verify a single function in mockito?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the old question is just wrong.  And it was wrong at that time as well.

You read that "mocks are callable" and that just means

```
m = mock()
m()  # => None
```

mocks are pre-configured to be callable.  That's a special case because otherwise plain mocks are totally dumb.  (The user has to configure them.)

But here you don't even want mocks, you want to patch (or: monkey-patch) functions.  Actually, you don't patch functions (what does that mean) you monkey patch the *module* the fucntion lives in.  The module is also an object.

Consider:

```
def interesting():
    also()
```

If you call `interesting()`, python stumbles upon the name `also` and looks that up, first in the local function scope, and then in the outer, global, module scope.  That means, if you replace `<module>.also` you get the desired effect in not calling the "real" function `also` but a fake one.

So the general form

```
# the test.py
import some_module as module_under_test

def test_1():
    when(module_under_test).also()
    ...
    unstub()  # t.i. restore/undo the patching
```

Having a test file and an implementation file makes this easy because patching the test module while you're in the test module -- that is your example:  `interesting_function` lives in the test file -- you usually don't know what to patch, but it is actually `sys.modules[__name__]` that is your current module object.

Comment: I had to import the whole module (not a standalone function) and only then I was able to patch it. Looks not really rational when I need only one function from that module.

Comment: That's too ambiguous.  Both is possible.

Comment: If I import in the 'main' tested file a function in this way `from module import function` and I patch it in the 'test' file this way `when(module).function().thenReturn()' (the whole module is imported in the test file) - the call won't be recognized. I need to import the whole module in the 'tested' file as well - then it works finely.

Comment: Ah, yes, you have to patch the "main" module. E.g `when(main).function()`.